# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot, jpa

I am studying Spring Boot.
I want to refer to the MySQL data and display the MySQL data in Thymeleaf.
But, I get the following error:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column
> 'employee0_.department_department_id' in 'field list'.

Also, I want to set to refer to Department class from Employee class. (@ManyToOne)
But I'm not sure if the current Entity class and MySQL settings are correct.

**EmployeeController**

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    private final EmployeeRepository emRepository;
    private final DepartmentRepository deRepository;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showList(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("employeeList", emRepository.findAll());
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/add")
    public String addEmployee(@ModelAttribute Employee employee, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("departmentList", deRepository.findAll());
        return "form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/save")
    public String process(@Validated @ModelAttribute Employee employee, BindingResult result) {

        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "form";
        }
        emRepository.save(employee);
        return "index";
    }

    @GetMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public String editEmployee(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("employee", emRepository.findById(id));
        return "form";
    }

    @GetMapping("/delete/{id}")
    public String deleteEmployee(@PathVariable Long id) {
        emRepository.deleteById(id);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

**Department**

```
package com.example.demo.model;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="department_id")
    private Long department_id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 40)
    @Column(name="department_name")
    private String department_name;


    public Department(String name) {
        this.department_name = name;

    }
}
```

**Employee**

```
package com.example.demo.model;
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 40)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private Department department;
}
```

**DepartmentRepository**

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.example.demo.model.Department;

public interface DepartmentRepository  extends JpaRepository<Department, Long> {

}
```

**EmployeeRepository**

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.example.demo.model.Employee;

public interface EmployeeRepository  extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {

}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Employee List</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h3>List</h3>
    <div th:if="${employeeList.size==0}">
        <h3>no data</h3>
    </div>

    <table th:if="${employeeList.size()>0}">

        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>Department</th>
            <th></th>

        </tr>


        <tr th:each="employee:${employeeList}" th:object="${employee}">

            <td th:text="${employee.id}"></td>
            <td th:text="${employee.name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${employee.department_name}"></td>

            <td><form th:action="@{'/delete/'+${employee.id}}" method="post">
                    <button>delete</button>
                </form></td>
            <td><form th:action="@{'/edit/'+${employee.id}}" method="post">
                    <button>edit</button>
                </form></td>

        </tr>
    </table>

    <h3>
        <a th:href="@{/add}">add</a>
    </h3>
</body>
</html>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_crud
spring.datasource.username=spring_crud
spring.datasource.password=spring_crud
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
#spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

[image]

Comment: In your employee class, I think you need to add @JoinColumn(name = "department_id") and you should add the department_id as a foreign key in the foreign key tab.

Comment: I added `@JoinColumn` . it worked  correctly! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try add annotation `@JoinColumn(name = "department_id")` under your department data in your Employee class. Or more detail like,

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 40)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Department.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", referencedColumnName = "department_id")
    private Department department;
}
```

Also, I suggest to not use the column `department_name` on your employee class (also in database).  You can get the attribute using getter after fetching the data. e.g. `employee.getDepartment().getDepartment_name()`.

Comment: This worked correctly. Thank you!

But, getting the Name of the Department did not work.

When `<td th: text = "$ {employee.department}">` or `<td th: text = "$ {employee.getDepartment ()}">`, the name of the department is "com.example.demo.model.Department". @ 5d9db059 "is displayed.
An error occurs when the code is `<td th: text = "$ {employee.getDepartment (). GetDepartment_Name ()}">`. "org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException"
Do I need to add code in the Employee class?

Comment: Can you try `<td th: text = "${employee.getDepartment().getDepartment_name()}">`